# How to create alias for users in Gnu/linux?

Tags: linux, manjaro

I am two users, user1 and user2, and I want to create an alias that have as member the 2 users. How to do this? 
I am looking for this:

```
alias usersMem='user1, user2'
```

But this code don't work. It shows me:

```
bash: alias: user1: not found
bash: alias: user2: not found
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Not with alias, that is for something else. Can you tell us what your goal is? I think I may have an answer, but it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is a homework. I am noob in Linux. The goal is know more about linux.

Comment: What does the homework say?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to put the two users into a `group` and work with this.
As I understand it, the `alias` function is meant more for `commands` and not for `users`.